# Como classificar a os comentários mais uteis de uma tabela?

Tags: java, sql

Um seguinte cenário:

Cada Produto tem um comentário, cada comentário ira receber um like para informar se foi útil (é opcional informar se gostou do comentário)

Eu tenho uma tabela chamada CustomerReview e uma tabela chamada likeReview e dentro dessa tabela eu tenho a coluna isLike(valores true,falso ou null).Preciso ordenar essa tabela tal forma que os comentários com mais likes positivos ficam no topo da lista.

Como posso fazer isso?

Meu código SQL dá erro quando eu tento ordenar pelo isLike, Pois, haverá comentários da tabela CustomerReview que não estarão associados com a tabela Likereview

**Código SQL:**

```sql
SELECT {c.pk}FROM { CustomerReview c LEFT JOIN     LikeReview l     ON {c.pk  "} = {l.pk} }WHERE {c.product} = ?product AND      {c.LANGUAGE  } = ?languageGROUP BY {c.pk}ORDER BY SUM(CASE WHEN {l.ISLIKE } = "true" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que eu entendi de sua explicação, para cada registro em CustomerReview eu posso ter um ou mais  registros na tabela LikeReview, sendo que alguns podem estar marcados com o campo islike como true.

Para trazer os customerReview com maior quantidade de likes marcados como true, você poderia fazer assim:

```html
SELECT {c.pk}FROM { CustomerReview c 
LEFT JOIN     
LikeReview l     
ON {c.pk  "} = {l.fk} }
WHERE {c.product} = ?product 
AND      {c.LANGUAGE  } = ?language
AND {l.ISLIKE } = "true"
GROUP BY {c.pk}
ORDER BY COUNT({l.pk}) DESC
```

Comment: Eu tenho esse erro aqui usando essa consulta que você me sugeriu: cannot search unknown field 'TableField(name='isLike',langPK='null',type=CustomerReview)'

Comment: Exatamente como você entendeu , mas como é opcional eu notificar se gostei do comentário.Entao, pode haver CustomerReview sem likeReview